# Are there any minuses with having 2 DHCP servers at home?

Tags: home-networking

At home, I have 2 D-link devices: the ADSL modem and the wireless router.

Both offer a DHCP server, that I have activated (on different subnets) on both devices, with no problems so far.

*Are there any minuses about that configuration (performance, security, ...)?*

Comment: There are no problems but this seems like a really weird setup. Is your modem connected to the WAN port on your router and, if so, why did you activate the DHCP server on both? What clients are you expecting to serve that your router's DHCP server doesn't serve? Does your modem have a built-in router? Are you actually using the two different subnets?

Comment: Well, sometimes I use the wireless device for "intranet" use (commnunication among home device), leaving the ADSL mode off. And yes, you are right, the modem is on the wan port of the router

Comment: Your hard-wired and wireless subnets will not easily be able to see each other, eg for sharing files, etc. Unless this is what you want for security reasons, you would be better to operate the wireless router in access point mode, so that the wireless devices are on the same subnet as the wired ones, both using the ADSL modem's DHCP.